# alias with dash in Input in Angular

Tags: angular

i have a component who has an @Input with alias

```
export class MyComponent() {
     @Input('my-alias') alias: string
}
```

And i want get this @Input like that:

```
<app-mycomponent [my-alias]="'my alias'"></app-mycomponent>
```

But it's not work. I must configure something?

Comment: Are you importing the Input decorator from the `@angular/core` package? I tested your code and it works for me.

Comment: Please create an [mcve] to see what you are missing. You can use https://stackblitz.com as well